Problem with indexing a mathematical formulation
I have an issue where a variable, V, is triggered by a gurobi linear expression for a scheduling problem and this trigger initiates access to a static sequence for each cell. E.g. for react_cellX[a,b,c]. This is a static sequence of fixed length linked to the planning horizon by the trigger of V. If it helps, this static sequence must be accessed sequentially, with no gaps in both index and time, until it ends, in the planning horizon.
Meaning if the first instance of this variable V is at $t=X$, therefore in the objective function we have: v[cellx,X] element_cellx[0] then at $x+1$ we access v[cellx,X] element_cellx[1] AND len(react_cellX)==sum of variable V for cellX).
I am stuck because indexing for what I'm thinking depended on the start/trigger for V but I am having difficulty capturing the start explicitly as it's defined by a gurobi linear expression. I think introducing additional variables is overkill and costly for such an issue when the entire model works, just this error I picked while testing (this was the last bit of the code).

Could you provide (the relevant parts of) your mathematical formulation?

Basically by trigger/access you mean a binary variable that fires (turns 1 in programming language) upon a condition (variable $V$ triggering/switching ON or turning 1).
So
$V_{cx,x} \le cell_{x,k} \quad \forall k \in [1 , \vert V_{xc} \vert] \ \ \forall x$ if len ($V_{cx}$) is constant or pre-defined parameter or a value that is computed outside the math model/solver
If the lenght is also a variable, then
$V_{cx,x} \le cell_{x,0}$
$\sum_{t=1}^{T}cell_{x,t} \le \sum_{cx}V_{cx,x} $
$cell_{x,t-1}+ cell_{x,t+1} \le cell_{x,t}+1 \quad \forall t \in [1, T] \ \ \forall x$
